# Getting rsSharePointError page when trying to access SQL Reporting server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I'm setting up SQL Reporting services with SharePoint integration. I've created my new reporting database, installed the SharePoint Web Front End Role on the reporting server, installed the reporting add in on all my WFEs and run through the configuration in central admin.

I'm running MOSS 2007 SP2 and SRS 2005 SP2

I've got all green checks across my reproting services configuration, but if I try to browse to the Report Server virtual directory, I get the following error.

> Reporting Services Error
>
> Report
> Server has encountered a SharePoint
> error. (rsSharePointError) Get Online
> Help Access to this Web site has been
> blocked. Please contact the
> administrator to resolve this problem.
> Access to this Web site has been
> blocked. Please contact the
> administrator to resolve this problem.
>
> SQL Server Reporting Services

If I take a look at the logs, I get some more detail.

> w3wp!library!1!2/11/2010-18:18:23:: e
> ERROR: Throwing
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.SharePointException:
> Report Server has encountered a
> SharePoint error., ;  Info:
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.SharePointException:
> Report Server has encountered a
> SharePoint error. --->
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException:
> Access to this Web site has been
> blocked.
>
> Please contact the administrator to
> resolve this problem. --->
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
> (0x81020071): Access to this Web site
> has been blocked.
>
> Please contact the administrator to
> resolve this problem.    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetSiteFlags(String
> bstrUrl)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetSiteFlags(String
> bstrUrl)    --- End of inner exception
> stack trace ---    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetSiteFlags(String
> bstrUrl)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.get_ReadLocked()
> at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.Server.SharePointImpersonatedWeb.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace --- w3wp!security!1!2/11/2010-18:18:23:: i
> INFO: Exception while running with
> elevated privileges
> w3wp!security!1!2/11/2010-18:18:23:: i
> INFO: Report Server has encountered a
> SharePoint error.
> w3wp!webserver!1!2/11/2010-18:18:23::
> e ERROR: Reporting Services error
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.SharePointException:
> Report Server has encountered a
> SharePoint error. --->
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException:
> Access to this Web site has been
> blocked.
>
> Please contact the administrator to
> resolve this problem. --->
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
> (0x81020071): Access to this Web site
> has been blocked.
>
> Please contact the administrator to
> resolve this problem.    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetSiteFlags(String
> bstrUrl)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetSiteFlags(String
> bstrUrl)    --- End of inner exception
> stack trace ---    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetSiteFlags(String
> bstrUrl)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.get_ReadLocked()
> at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.Server.SharePointImpersonatedWeb.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.Server.SharePointImpersonatedWeb.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
> at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.Server.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__3()
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevatedWrapper(Object
> state)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__2()
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
> secureCode)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback
> secureCode, Object param)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated
> secureCode)    at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.Server.Utility.RunElevated(CodeToRunElevated
> code)    at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.Server.SharePointImpersonatedWeb.ImpersonateSharePointSiteByUserName(String
> wssUrl, String userName)    at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.Server.SharePointImpersonatedWeb.GetSharePointImpersonatedWeb(String
> wssUrl, UserContext userContext)    at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.Server.SharePointDBInterface.internalFindObjectsNonRecursive(String
> wssUrl, CatalogItemList& children)
> at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.Server.SharePointDBInterface.FindObjectsNonRecursive(String
> wssUrl, CatalogItemList& childList,
> Security secMgr, IPathTranslator
> pathTranslator, Boolean
> appendMyReports)    at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ListChildrenAction.PerformActionNow()
> at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.RSSoapAction`1.Execute()
> at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportServiceHttpHandler.RenderFolder()
> at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportServiceHttpHandler.RenderPageContent()
> at
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportServiceHttpHandler.RenderPage()

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the ReportServer virtual directory is being processed by SharePoint still. You need to set it up as an exclusion in SharePoint. To do this, switch to the SharePoint 12 hive (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\bin) and run the command:

```
stsadm -o addpath -url http://<sharepointurl>/<ReportServer vdir> -type exclusion
stsadm -o addpath -url http://<sharepointurl>/<Reports vdir> -type exclusion
```

Comment: Hi Matt, 

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but as far as I can tell the Reporting Services Virtual Directory isn't a SharePoint site. It's a virtual directory  that gets created by the SQL Reporting Services 2005 configuration tool

Comment: @Brian - sorry, I locked in on the actual error without realizing it was SSRS - changed my answer to reflect what I think the problem actually is.

Comment: @Matt - Thanks. That looked promising, but I'm running MOSS 2007 SP2 and when I tried to add the exlusion I got this message "Exclusions are no longer necessary. SharePoint will detect existing files and virtual directories in the same IIS Web Site and allow them to be served by IIS." Which is nice, I guess, but leaves me back at square 1.

Comment: @Brian - I didn't know that about SP2, sorry. What type of authentication are you using for your site?

Comment: Windows Integrated Authentication. NTLM

Comment: This probably isn't anything, but I would check to make sure that IIS really is setup for NTLM. Assuming it is - I'm not sure where to go from here other than trying to uninstall/reinstall SSRS.